# Query execution speed when finding SUM

Tags: php, mysql

In database,i have accounts details table, that contain approx.,300000 records based on the below query I have to show the report in table,  account name and selected company value in year-wise, nearly 40 rows and 13 columns

I have the query,

```
$sql = ("SELECT sum(value) as val FROM balancesheet where formula='$formulaid' and year='$year' and nse_code='$companyCode'");
```

based on the year, company, and formula, here formula field, suppose if formula is 1+2+3 means, the 
query will execute 3 times inside the loop and continue again with parent loop

o/p: will be like

```
        2012      2011     2000.........
account name1   15.00     16.08    47.55
account name2   15.00     16.08    47.55
.......
```

so hardly it takes 4 to 5 mins to print. 
Kindly help me how to improve the execution of query to print faster

Comment: What keys did you define in your table?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how `formula` works?

Answer (score 2):

If these columns are always searched together, define an index on them,

```
ALTER TABLE balancesheet ADD INDEX (formula, year, nse_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to find out what is happening under the bonnet (hood for the Yanks). Then you are in a position to create the appropriate indexes.

The indexes can be created via the table definition or via [create index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html). It is also useful to look into [optimize](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes on where fields to improve speed.